# Do WIFI access points relay transmissions or just facilitate transactions between two machines connected to it?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, wifi-configuration, 802.11n, 802.11ac

I'm wondering about the specifics of the way infrastructure Wi-Fi devices operate. I'd always assumed that all data is transmitted to the router, and then broadcasted out to the relevant device.

I'd imagine that in some scenarios the router could be used to facilitate a connection between two devices that are already connected.

For Ex:

Device1 is sending a 50MB File to Device2.
One would assume it would make more sense for the following setup:

Device1 <----> Device2 (Router setups the conversation between the two devices and leaves them alone to finish it)

Rather than:

Device1<-----> wifi router <-------> Device 2

In summary does the wifi router **Always** need to serve as the middle man?

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If two 802.11 STAs ("Wi-Fi clients") are connected to an 802.11 Access Point (abbreviated "AP", a.k.a. "Wi-Fi router"), then every packet transmitted between the two STAs is actually transmitted from the first STA to the AP, and then from the AP to the second STA. This is called "Intra-BSS Relay", and it's done to avoid what's known as the "hidden node problem", where both STAs are in range of the AP, but they are not in range of each other.

It's nice that this solves the hidden node problem, but it means that wireless-to-wireless transmissions cross the same channel twice, taking roughly twice as much airtime as would really be needed if the two STAs could talk directly to each other.

To help avoid that waste of airtime, an addendum to the 802.11 standard has added something known as "Tunneled Direct Link Setup" (TDLS) to allow two STAs on the same AP to talk directly to each other when they are in range of each other. However, I'm not sure how many STAs actually support TDLS. I wouldn't be surprised if it's just a neat idea that got into the standard but never gets used.

There have also been various ways developed for two 802.11 STAs to talk to each other directly regardless of whether or not they're joined to the same network or any network at all. Wi-Fi Direct was an early attempted that never caught on in the market. Apple used a proprietary solution akin to a stripped-down Wi-Fi Direct to create the AirDrop feature for OS X Lion. Apple then created a different solution called Apple Wireless Direct Link (AWDL) to allow iOS devices to do AirDrop. Eventually an updated form of AWDL came to OS X; that was when you could finally AirDrop between Macs and iOS devices. Apple also uses AWDL to allow Macs and iOS devices to do "AirPlay" A/V streaming and screen mirroring to nearby Apple TVs even when they are not on the same network. Apple took an AWDL-like proposal to the Wi-Fi Alliance where it became known as "Neighbor Aware Networking" (NAN) and is now being marketed by the alliance as "Wi-Fi Aware". It remains to be seen whether "Wi-Fi Aware" will truly be interoperable enough and reliable enough to catch on in the marketplace where Wi-Fi Direct failed.

Answer (score 0):

This post does contain the answers you are looking for, but is a bit complex because the question would appear vaguely worded.  I've tried to bold the answers to your questions as well.

First off, A Wireless Access Point is different to a Wifi Router.

From a "Logical" POV, Access points act exactly like a wireless switch (arguably a hub) - in fact, for traffic not addressed to them, they do not care about the payload, let alone routing, they simply pass information on.

**This means that if information is travelling locally it is never passed to the router** - the same as if you have multiple devices connected via a switch.  The mechanism which determines how data travels is at a higher level then the AP works - specifically its defined by the subnet mask and how various devices respond - again, exactly like a switch would.

I note that **when 2 WIFI devices connected to the same AP talk to each other, the information does go to the AP then back out again**, rather then directly between the devices  (but it does not go near a router).  **This has to do with the WIFI protocols, and also because its entirely possible for 2 devices to both be able to see the access point but not each other.**

When you have a WIFI router, you can logically think of it as 2 devices combined into 1 - an Access point + a router, each performing its own task - and indeed if you disable Router functionality a router works perfectly as an Access Point.